# Where/how to learn about dark matter?

Tags: resource-recommendations, dark-matter

I am a physics student and as far as I know dark matter is beyond the topics included in my grade career. Are there any serious book on the subject? Any serious set of lectures somewhere in Internet?

Answer (score 4):

There is an excellent book by Iain Nicolson called "Dark Side Of The Universe" which covers this in great detail. I recommend it for the following reasons:

1) it furnishes a thorough historical overview of the problem, going back to the earliest work by Zwicky

2) it contains a detailed description of all the observational and instrumentation techniques used over the years by the astrophysics community to infer its presence and map its distribution

3) it provides an exhaustive list of all the potential candidates for dark matter particles and a discussion of why or why not they are viable

4) it ties the topic together with an equally thorough discussion of dark energy

5) it explains the connection between dark matter, dark energy and cosmology

6) it is accessible by nonspecialists

Comment: So is this more of a pop-sci book than technical book?

Comment: no. it is highly technical and encyclopedic in detail, but contains no equations.

Comment: I'm confused how something can be highly technical but includes no equations, especially when discussing cosmology and dark energy.

Comment: @kylekanos, there are different levels of abstraction and math that an author can use, depending on the sophistication level of the intended audience. Nicolson seems to have pitched his exposition at people who have college degrees but are not practitioners in the field. As such I admit it might not satisfy someone with your level of training.